# Does hashing the first & last few bytes of a file generally result in accuracy for detecting changes?

Tags: hash, md5

If I take file A and then modify it slightly to save it as file B, generate a full MD5 hash on both, they will expectedly be different hashes.

However to speed up the process especially when dealing with huge files and an enormous amount of them, I commonly see the recommendation to only hash the first and last couple of bytes of the files being hashed (or a specified number of bytes out of a file). This supposedly is still an effective way to detect changes between files although raises the amounts of potential false positives.

But, just how often is that the case and are there any better alternatives? When files get modified and saved, is it a safe assumption that the first or last bytes are typically modified by applications like Photoshop or Office applications? 100% accuracy isn't an expectation, but a good combination of speed and accuracy is preferred.

Comment: So you're dealing with any type of file formats? If you know the expected file formats, you can look at their specs and see if the first/last bytes are likely to change. If you're dealing with unknown file formats, seems a little dangerous. Take a plain text file where the middle of the document is changed: your method wouldn't detect a change!

Comment: "I commonly see the recommendation to only hash the first and last couple of bytes of the files being hashed." Can you link to those recommendations?

Comment: Many files have common headers and footers (my entire c++ project files for example), which would make this scheme useless. I'd suggest sampling a set of static locations throughout the file, if you're so intent on reduced coverage. But then again - on some systems it may have the same performance as scanning the entire file.